# STL Vector and Map which should prefer while deleting set of records

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

In STL, which is better Map or Vector. Suppose i have a set of records which needs to be deleted, then what should i prefer - std::map or std::vector. Why?

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve.  Right now it makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably think of using a Set instead of Map if you dont have anything like a key-value pair and its just values that you have. I'm assuming this since you're talking about using a vector

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add and delete many records in unpredictable order, the map or a set will probably perform better. This is because deleting an entry only takes logarithmic time proportional to the size of the map or set, whereas deleting an entry from the vector takes time proportional to the size of the vector. unordered_map / unordered_set may be even better - cost of deleting a record will typically be constant.

For background:

- vector is an array, so if you delete a single element all the other elements need to move one to the left.
- map and set are red-black trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)
- unordered_map and unordered_set are hash tables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)